# How setting window variables in Jest

Tags: import, jestjs

I was trying to test my application using Jest.

But I don't know how to set a variable `window.objEnv` in this context.

I read a lot of solutions, but I don't know how do it in my case.

The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'strB' of undefined

BS[window.objEnv.strB](BC);
                 ^
```

mytest.test.js

```
// I would like to set like this
window.objEnv = {
    "strB": "xyz"
};

import HM from "~/app/HM.js";
```

HM.js

```
import BSR from "./env/BSR.js";

const BS = {
    xyz: BSR
};

BS[window.objEnv.strB](BC);
```

My `window.objEnv` is set in a PHP file.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`import` statements are hoisted. A way to set mocked global before it's accessed in a module is to use `require`:

```
window.objEnv = {
    "strB": "xyz"
};

const HM = require("~/app/HM.js").default;
...
```